# VS Setup Project - Sqlexpresschk.exe is not a valid win32 application when ran from Win XP KN Pro SP3

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, installation, windows-xp-sp3, vsinstaller

I need your help - I have a problem with getting a VS Setup to work on Windows XP KN SP3 because I encounter an error with Microsoft SQL Express Version Checker executable because "SqlExpressChk.exe is not a valid Win32 application" and I do not know how to fix it, having tried a lot of things already. Details follow.

I have a VS Setup project with 3 pre-requisites that are to be installed from the local machine (not downloaded). They are .NET 4 Framework, SQL Server 2008 R2 and Windows Installer 4.5. I have downloaded all the necessary bootstrapper files from MS Download Center and saved to the my local dev machine so the VS Setup project builds fine.

I am testing the Setup on Windows KN SP3 (running on Hyper-V) however when you run the setup, the following error occurs:
[image: SqlExpressChk.exe is not a valid Win32 application error]

Which suggests that the executable is 64-bit. Why is Setup using a 64-bit version of the checker if it knows that we are on a 32-bit machine? If I can get my hands on a 32-bit version of this checker, then maybe the setup will continue, but I cannot find any.

Install log shows the following (although it maybe wrong, since if sqlexpresschk.exe wasn't run, then how would the logger know the actual values?):

`Running checks for package 'SQL Server 2008 R2 Express', phase BuildList
Running external check with command 'SqlExpress2008R2\SqlExpressChk.exe' and parameters '10.50.1600 1033'
Process exited with code 0
Setting value '0 {int}' for property 'SQLExpressChk'
The following properties have been set for package 'SQL Server 2008 R2 Express':
Property: [SQLExpressChk] = 0 {int}
Running checks for command 'SqlExpress2008R2\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotExists' on property 'VersionNT': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '5.1.3': false
Result of running operator 'VersionEqualTo' on property 'VersionNT' and value '5.2.0': false
Result of running operator 'VersionEqualTo' on property 'VersionNT' and value '5.2.1': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'SQLExpressChk' and value '-1': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'SQLExpressChk' and value '-2': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'SQLExpressChk' and value '-3': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'SQLExpressChk' and value '-4': false
Result of running operator 'ValueLessThan' on property 'SQLExpressChk' and value '-4': false
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'Intel': false
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'SQLExpressChk' and value '1': true
Result of checks for command 'SqlExpress2008R2\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'SqlExpress2008R2\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'Intel': false
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'SQLExpressChk' and value '2': true
Result of checks for command 'SqlExpress2008R2\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'SqlExpress2008R2\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'amd64': true
Result of checks for command 'SqlExpress2008R2\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'SqlExpress2008R2\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'amd64': true
Result of checks for command 'SqlExpress2008R2\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE' is 'Bypass'
'SQL Server 2008 R2 Express' RunCheck result: No Install Needed`

It is bypassing the install, because of

```
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'SQLExpressChk' and value '1': true
```

Since in package.xml:

```
<BypassIf Property="SQLExpressChk" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="1"/>
```

I don't understand what does that value reflect, but maybe one of you do?

What do you think?

Regards,
Sergey

p.s.

Things I've tried include re-downloading the packges, re-building the project, installing sql server 2008 r2 on the target windows xp machine (setup runs fine on its own, btw) and trying to find a local version of the version checker, but couldn't find one. Even trying to modify EF Models to work on SQL CE so I wouldn't need to depend on SQL Express, but I get a separate problem in EF which prevents me from doing that. Restarting win xp many times.

Comment: Did you ever have luck with this?  I'm trying to use the VS2013 Setup project, clicking SQL Server 2008 R2 Express as a prereq, and I get the "Not a valid Win32 application" error.

Comment: No - I ended up refactoring my EF model to work with SQL CE in the end. I would recommend using a WIX installer project vs vs setup generally and maybe using WIX will magically fix this error. Personally, for me, WIX all the way from now on - solid documentation and tons of options.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.  First, I backed up C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlExpress2008R2\SqlExpressChk.exe.  Then, I copied the SqlExpressChk.exe from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlExpress2008 to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlExpress2008R2.

I found another article online that verified that I wasn't crazy: https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-offline-clickonce-application/